# Convert a List of objects to a Map using Streams

Tags: java

I have a list of objects of class A:

```
List<A> list;
class A {
    String name;
    String lastname;
    //Getter and Setter methods
}
```

I want to convert this list to a map from name to a set of lastnames:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> map;
```

For example, for the following list:

John Archer, John Agate, Tom Keinanen, Tom Barren, Cindy King

The map would be:

John -> {Archer, Agate}, Tom -> {Keinanen, Barren}, Cindy -> {King}

I tried the following code, but it returns a map from name to objects of class A:

```
list.stream.collect(groupingBy(A::getFirstName, toSet()));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Map< String, Set<String>> map = list.stream()
                                    .collect(
                                        Collectors.groupingBy(
                                              A::getFirstName, Collectors.mapping(
                                                    A::getLastName, Collectors.toSet())));
```

You were on the right track you need to use:

- `Collectors.groupingBy` to group by the `firstName`.
- And then use  a downstream collector like `Collectors.mappping` as a second parameter  of `Collectors.groupingBy` to map to the `lastName` .
- And then finally collect that in a `Set<String>` by invoking `Collectors.toSet`:

Answer (score 2):

You never told the collector to extract last names.

I suppose you need something like

```java
list.stream
  .collect(groupingBy(
    A::getFirstName, // The key is extracted.
    mapping(  // Map the stream of grouped values.
      A::getLastName, // Extract last names.
      toSet()  // Collect them into a set.
)));
```